# SQL Server programming error: incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'

Tags: sql-server, pyodbc

For some reason I get a programming error when I try to run this:

```
CREATE TABLE BTS_songs_10M_likes 
AS
    SELECT Song, "Views(M)", "Views_in_first_24_hrs(M)", Release_Date
    FROM BTS_top_10_songs
    WHERE "Likes(M)" > 10
    ORDER BY "Likes(M)" DESC, "Views(M)" DESC;
```

The error:

> mssql+pyodbc://sa:***@SQL
> (pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'. (156) (SQLExecDirectW)")
>
> [SQL: /* Create a table for BTS songs with more than 10M likes (excluding "Likes(M)" and "Dislikes(M)" columns) */
> CREATE TABLE BTS_songs_10M_likes AS
> SELECT Song, "Views(M)", "Views_in_first_24_hrs(M)", Release_Date
> FROM BTS_top_10_songs
> WHERE "Likes(M)" > 10
> ORDER BY "Likes(M)" DESC, "Views(M)" DESC;]
> (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/f405)

How can I solve this and what is the reason for this error?

I am using SQL Server 2019

Comment: You can't create a table like this. There's no `CREATE TABLE AS .... SELECT`. Were you trying to create a view perhaps?

Comment: Or `SELECT INTO`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos [link](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_create_table.asp) The last part of this website says that I can create a table like this

Comment: So this site is wrong. It won't be the first time. Why don't you check SQL Server's documentation instead? If you want to create a table filled with the results of a query use SELECT INTO

Comment: Okay thank you I will use SELECT INTO instead

Comment: That syntax does work on [MS Azure Synapse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-as-select-azure-sql-data-warehouse?view=aps-pdw-2016-au7). But not the more common versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version of SQL Server are you using? The syntax "CREATE TABLE <table_name> AS " won't work for SQL Server 2008 and older. If that's the case, use the syntax [SELECT INTO](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/queries/select-into-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2019

Comment: No SQL Server edition supports `CREATE TABLE AS SELECT`